# cannot find symbol- class KeyEvent

Tags: java

I am trying to make a brickBreaker game with the help of a video but when I compile I get an error in my public voids that involve KeyEvent towards the bottom of the code.

I get the error as follows:

> cannot find symbol-class KeyEvent.

```
package brickBreaker;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Timer;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Gameplay extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener{
private boolean play = false;
private int score = 0;

private int totalBricks = 21;

private Timer time;
private int delay = 8;

private int playerX = 310;

private int ballposX = 120;
private int ballposY = 350;
private int balldirX = -1;
private int balldirY = -2;

private MapGenerator map;

public Gameplay(){
    map = new MapGenerator(3, 7);
    addKeyListener(this);
    addActionListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
   // timer = new Timer(delay, this);
   // timer.start();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    //background
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(1,1, 692, 592);

    //Drawing map
    map.draw((Graphics2D)g);

    //borders
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillRect(0,0,3,592);
    g.fillRect(0,0,692,3);
    g.fillRect(691, 0, 3, 592);

    //the paddle
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(playerX, 550, 100, 8);

    //the ball
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillOval(ballposX, ballposY, 20, 20);

    g.dispose();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    timer.start();

    if(play){
        if(new Rectangle(ballposX, ballposY, 20, 20).intersects(new Rectangle(playerX, 550, 100, 8))){
            balldirY = -balldirY;
        }

       A: for(int i = 0; i < map.map.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<map.map[0].length; j++){
                if(map.map[i][j] > 0){
                    int brickX = j* map.brickwidth + 80;
                    int brickY = i * map.brickheight +50;
                    int brickwidth = map.brickwidth;
                    int brickheight = map.brickheight;

                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(brickX, brickY, brickwidth, brickheight);
                    Rectangle ballRect= new Rectangle(ballposX, ballposY, 20, 20);
                    Rectangle brickRect = rect;

                    if(ballRect.intersects(brickRect)){
                        map.setBrickValue(0, i, j);
                        totalBricks--;
                        score += 5;

                        if(ballposX + 1 <= brickRect.x || ballposX+1 >= brickRect.x+brickRect.width){
                            balldirX = -balldirX;
                        } else{
                            balldirY = -balldirY;
                        }
                        break A;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ballposX += balldirX;
        ballposY+= balldirY;
        if(ballposX < 0){
            balldirX = -balldirX; 
        }
        if(ballposY < 0){
            balldirY = -balldirY; 
        }
        if(ballposX > 670){
            balldirX = -balldirX; 
        }
    }

    repaint();
} 
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        if(playerX >= 600){
            playerX = 600;
        } else{
            moveRight();
        }
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        if(playerX >= 10){
            playerX = 10;
        } else{
            moveLeft();
        }
    }
}  
public void moveRight(){
    play = true;
    playerX+=20;
}

public void moveLeft(){
    play = true;
    playerX-=20;
}

}
```

Comment: why `import static` ?

Comment: import java.​awt.​event.​KeyEvent;

Comment: @Scary Wombat The static was a mistake I didn't notice, I guess it went unseen since it didn't give me an error. I removed it but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @santoshgore I already did import that if you check above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line `import java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;` to this `import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;`.

**EDIT**

You need to implement these two methods as well, as they are part of the `KeyListener` interface.

```
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO 
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO 
}
```

Comment: I tried it but now it says brickBreaker.Gameplay is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent) in java.awt.event.KeyListener

Comment: Yes, you have to implement all of the `KeyListener`'s methods. You have implemented only `keyPressed(KeyEvent e)`. The import statement fixes only this error **cannot find symbol-class KeyEvent**.

Comment: So how do I fix the second error I am getting and how do I implement everything that I need rather than only keyPressed(KeyEvent e)

Comment: Copy and paste the two methods that I've added in the EDIT section of the answer. If you don't need to handle key-released and key-typed events, just leave the method body empty.